# Button onPressed async method with 2 setState

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't figure out why 2 setState in async onPressed method causing error

> Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose():
>   _LoginScreenState#0eb2c(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)

Here is my code

```
 RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Login'),
      onPressed: emailController.text == "" || passwordController.text == ""
          ? null
          : () async {
              setState(() {
                _isLoading = true;
              });
              SharedPreferences prefs =
                  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
              prefs.setString('email', emailController.text);
              try {
                await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
                    .signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
              } on HttpException catch (error) {
                exceptionAlertDialog(context, error.toString());
              } catch (error) {
                exceptionAlertDialog(context, error.toString());
              }
              setState(() {
                _isLoading = false;
              });
            },
    )
```

once isLoading is true I display spinner.. Nothing extraordinary

```
body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: _isLoading
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : ListView(
                children: <Widget>[textSection(), buttonSection()],
              ),
      ),
```

Everything works fine if I comment out those 2 set state in the button onPressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put isLoading to dispose

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _isLoading = false;
    super.dispose();
  }
```